# I want to create a little test-program with "dices" with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how I can create a "game" where I have three dices, and three bets. If any of the bets hits, I will be granted 1 point, else nothing happens.

Example variables and arrays I would like to use;

```
var points = 1;

var slot1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
var slot2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
var slot3 = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);

var dices = [slot1, slot2, slot3];

function Bet(bet1, bet2, bet3) {
   "NEED HELP WITH THE CODE HERE"
}

Bet(1,2,3);
```

Thanks alot for all kinds of help!

Comment: Should it be with HTML to be able to enter the bets? Or just plain javascript with console output? Actually this is not much code you provide us with.

Comment: Plain javascript, I am just trying to learn. Just console output.

Comment: the requirements are not precise enough. Could _you_ implement it definitively, given only that vague description? What are the rules? What's a "hit" (I assume it means the numbers match, but jargon should be explained)? Does the number for bet1 have to match dice 1, or can it match any of them? What should the final output look like? etc etc. Plus, what have you tried so far? Doesn't seem too much of a stretch to write some code to compare numbers to each other.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ SO isn't that kind of site, and to the others: don't enable this. Even the most basic free JS course will cover this.

Comment: You have assumed correctly, I would like the program to check if bet1 is the same as any of the dices, if it is, then points+1.
Then it checks if bet2 is the same as any of the dices, if it is, then points+1, and the same goes for bet3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nudge in the right direction is more appropriate than a ready-to-go answer, since your question smells a little bit like homework :-)

You basically need to cross-check each item from both lists. You can do this with either a nested `for .. in` loop or a call to `.some()` with a nested `.contains()`. The latter will give you the cleanest solution. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Alternatively, you can use Tagas' solution but that would make your function  less reusable. If the number of bets vary, you'll need to adjust your function..

Comment: Thanks alot, Fred! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function rollDice() {
    //generate a number between 1 to 6
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
}

function makeBet(bet1, bet2, bet3) {
    let slot1 = rollDice(),
        slot2 = rollDice(),
        slot3 = rollDice();

    console.log('Slot 1:', slot1);
    console.log('Slot 2:', slot2);
    console.log('Slot 3:', slot3);

    if(bet1 == slot1 || bet2 == slot2 || bet3 == slot3) {
        //return 1 point as there is a match
        return 1;
    }

    //return nothing as there was no match
    return 0;
}

//Make a bet!
makeBet(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: answer correct for OPs need, a simple complement to the accepted answer with actual code. Could be improved by actually turning this code into an executable snippet with some console.log on result.